# cake php not found anything

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, url-rewriting

When i use cake php(automation) in root of xamp or wamp it worked correct(with out virtual host).

But now use cake php in `http://85.9.95.52:8082/automation/`.

In this url cake php not found anythings(mycontroller,myView,...) even `http://85.9.95.52:8082/automation/css/base.css` in index page.

Index page say that all extension loaded and connect to database but not found anythings .

`httpd.conf`

```
  DocumentRoot "I:/PM3.0.5/processmaker/workflow/public_html"
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  <Directory  "I:/PM3.0.5/processmaker/workflow/public_html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all

        ExpiresActive On

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^.*/(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L,NC]
        </IfModule>
  </Directory>
  AliasMatch (?i)^/automation(.*)$ I:/PM3.0.5/automation/$1

  <Directory "I:/PM3.0.5/automation">
    RewriteEngine off
    Allow from all
    Options FollowSymlinks Indexes

  </Directory>
```

`I:/PM3.0.5/` is root directory and cakephp(automation) has in `I:/PM3.0.5/automation`

Any one can help me?

Comment: Can you provide the exact error message?

Comment: does not have error,only say not found

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `i:/PM3.0.5/` directory but maybe it was the directory of your local version and now you need to change it to the IP/url of the current server?

Comment: you can see index cake in `http://85.9.95.52:8082/automation/` but not found any controller

Comment: @ashkufaraz did you check your rewrite module setting? Is it enabled?

Comment: @Barebdra Vaghela yes it is enabled

Comment: also you ned allow overwrite in that directory , now your htaccess not working

Comment: try adding 
AllowOverride All
before last closing of directory : 
       AllowOverride All
</directory>

Comment: ` AllowOverride All` not worked